# For UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource, is it possible to direct cell update for a given section/ row, without having to build entire snapshot?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

For `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`, I was wondering, is it ever possible, to perform direct cell update for a give section/ row, without having to build the entire `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot` snapshot?

Sometimes, I need to perform a real-time continuous update, on a selected section/ selected row. Having to build the entire data source snapshot for every single real-time update, doesn't seem to be very efficient.

If that is possible, may I know what are the steps involved?

If that is not possible, is it because due to the design decision of `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` framework?

Comment: It's not inefficient. The data are Hashable. And anyway you don't "build" the snapshot. You fetch it from the data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since iOS15, we have an efficient way to update selected item row

```
private func reconfigureRecordingRow(_ recording: Recording) {
    var snapshot = dataSource.snapshot()
    snapshot.reconfigureItems([recording])
    dataSource.apply(snapshot)
}

private func makeDataSource() -> DataSource {
    let dataSource = DataSource(
        collectionView: collectionView,
        cellProvider: { [weak self] (collectionView, indexPath, anyHashable) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            guard let self = self else { return nil }

            guard let recordingCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
                withReuseIdentifier: "recording",
                for: indexPath) as? RecordingCell else {
                return nil
            }
```

When `reconfigureRecordingRow` is called, cellProvider's function will be executed.

`collectionView.dequeueReusableCell` is able to re-use **existing** `UICollectionViewCell`, without constructing new `UICollectionViewCell`